# MVC3 application, on existing architecture

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a entity framework driven solution, on top of which, I have a business layer and a service layer, exposing methods to my test console application. The console app has no idea about my entity framework. I have a transformation class which takes entity framework data objects, and transfers them into custom DTOs, which are in a shared library project. So, my database access layer uses the shared library, as does my other layers.

Now, I want to try build an MVC3 application. So, is it correct to build that as a separate project in my solution, and then have the controller part of the MVC application reference the service layer of my current solution? For example, my service layer exposes a method called "GetAllUsers", which returns a List. And then I take that List, and form a Model (M part of MVC), and pass that to the view. Does that seem OK?

Comment: Craig != Craig.

Comment: Thanks! So, just confirming... my method of doing things is OK, and, recommended? Is there a better architecture, or is this pretty standard? The only thing I question is that I transform my Entity objects to DTOs, and then I guess I will be transforming my DTOs into View Models when I want to present them. Seem OK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a big specialist but I think it's ok, and correct. Based on my experience of creating MVC applications, it is correct to separate the MVC application itself and other parts of entire solution such as database, database model or database model classes, database repositories, business models and others. Also, if You want, You can create a ViewModel classes dirrectly in MVC application project, based on your service layer. Namely create one more abstraction level, and use controller only for sending results to view and not for processing your List.

Answer (score 1):

To echo Dima - you may consider again mapping your DTO's to custom `ViewModel` classes specifically tailored to views (otherwise, you might find yourself having to use `ViewBag` etc to stuff additional data to the View).

Also to confirm that "M" of MVC is in effect the entire back end of the System (DAL, BLL, Service Layer, DTO's,   Entities etc). We typically delete the Model folder in asp.net MVC projects since the other layers are in separate assemblies and are referenced / injected. I'm assuming that your MVC front end is the 'primary' UI for your system (i.e. same team is developing MVC front end and the back end).

One moot point is the Service Layer - there are at least the following 2 options.

1. You can regard the service layer is for 'external' system consumers only, and allow your Controllers to interact directly with your BLL, or even (CQRS style) directly with the DAL/Repository for queries (i.e. Service Layer = exposed Integration Interfaces facade). (But your own front end Ajax calls etc should call MVC controller methods, not the service layer IMO)
2. Take the more traditional strict layered approach and regard the service layer as the gateway to your business layer (i.e. your MVC front isn't a special consumer of services at all and must go through the service layer).

With option 1, you may need to duplicate the service concerns in your Controller (security, transaction boundaries, logging etc). Typically controller would need these concerns anyway.

With option 2, e.g. if you are using WCF, you should try and avoid the additional network (and serialization / deserialization) overhead if possible. So if you find that you can deploy your MVC front end and Service layers in process to the same physical server, you can for instance configure an IoC (or classfactory) to inject your instances of WCF Service Contracts directly into your controller (i.e. so you are still going through the Service layer via the defined WCF contracts, but without the overhead).

Also with option 2, if you do have other systems consuming your services (other than your own front end), it can be advisable to formalize your interface, e.g. by an additional facade / mapping for external consumers. Otherwise, every time you add a new property or method to a WCF service for your own front end you will break the contract external consumers. WCF `MessageContract`s are useful for external systems interfaces, since you have finer level control over the message formats.